# SFDX: Grant type not supported

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to log in to an existing sandbox using the `sfdx force:auth:web:login`, which takes me to the login screen, I enter the password and email and I allow access, however in the browser I get a message: `localhost didn't send any data`, while in my CLI the message is `ERROR: grant type not supported.`

These are the requested permissions:

- Access your basic information
- Provide access to your data via the Web
- Access and manage your data
- Perform requests on your behalf at any time

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the domain name instead of the plain `test.salesforce.com`.

This **doesn't** work:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://xyz.lightning.force.com/ -a XYZ
```

but this works:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com/ -a XYZ
```

Comment: I did this.  To avoid the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388911/error-405-only-post-allowed-when-deploying-code-from-vscode-to-org, after this was done, I had to go to ~/.sfdx/appropriate.json and hand type in an instance url that replaced test.salesforce.com and restarted vscode.

Answer (score 17):

@smukov is correct, don't use the **lightning.force.com** url. Instead find that url here for your sandbox and log in using the instance that shows in the url during Log In or in the sandbox "location" column.

[image]

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Comment: As noted in another answer, you can also use *.my.salesforce.com urls; these are easily derived from *.lightning.force.com urls:  just replace "lightning.force.com" with "my.salesforce.com".  Works for prod and sandbox urls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JasonClark, this worked

Answer (score 12):

The fix for me was to use the URL that the dev org redirected to after logout.

So I:

1. Logged into the dev org
2. Logged out of the dev org
3. Copied the URL
4. Executed this command in the terminal:

   sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://random-domain-somenumber.my.salesforce.com -a DevHub

That did the trick for me

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me as well...Been stuck for hours.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have access to my production org at the time so this helped me get in

Answer (score 12):

Additionally, ensure you use "https" and not "http" (as I did)

"http" caused successful login on web resulting in following error
ERROR:  grant type not supported.

"https" solved it.

so, use "https://test.salesforce.com" and not "http://test.salesforce.com" (at least didn't worked for me).

Comment: This. CLI example shows http instead of https.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem while trying to authorize while doing trailhead challenges so there is no production, and `test.salesforce.com` somehow is not working.

If you are already logged in and don't want to log out to get the domain info, you can use `Domains` section from `Setup` menu and get the info from there to authorize your org.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to Authorize my Org and got below message:

```
ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  grant type not supported
```

I am running windows 10 and when I turned off my firewall and tried again the authorization worked.

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got this recently when I had a / at the end of the url so I was using https://blablabla.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/ and I had to use https://blablabla.sandbox.my.salesforce.com