# SFDX force:auth:web:login to Scratch Org other than one created by your CLI, Grant type not supported

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

[Similar question asked about logging into Sandboxes with this error SFDX: Grant type not supported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223205/sfdx-grant-type-not-supported); here we look at logging into scratch orgs.

**Given**:

- In your CLI you want to log into a scratch org that your CLI did not create. In my case, it was a scratch org created by our dev ops tool - Gearset.  But it could just as easily be a colleague's scratch org or one you created from a different computer.

**When**:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://xxx-yyy-zzz-dev-ed.lightning.force.com -a someAlias
```

- Successfully brings up a login screen
- You enter username and password for that scratch org
- CLI displays error `grant type not supported` and browser displays localhost error

### How does one login to such a scratch org?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in everything, the key is reading the [authorization documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_web_flow.htm) closely

If you happened to be logged into that scratch org from some other tool or browser, you note that the URL  for that org will look like:

```
Lightning: https://xxx-yyy-zzz-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/...
Classic: https://xxx-yyy-zzz-dev-ed.cs68.my.salesforce.com/
```

The [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_web_flow.htm) clearly states that you need to use  My Domain URL (scratch orgs have my domain enabled)

> If the org you are authorizing is on a My Domain subdomain, update your project configuration file (sfdx-project.json). Set the sfdcLoginUrl parameter to your My Domain login URL.

Where it is easy to get confused is that the doc for the `-r` or `--INSTANCEURL` parameter for `sfdx force:auth:web:login` is defined as `The login URL of the Salesforce instance that the org lives on.` and you get sloppy and just copy-paste what you see in the browser.

A domain ending in `...dev-ed.lightning.force.com/` is not a login URL

So, change the `-r` parameter to end in `my.salesforce.com`:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://xxx-yyy-zzz-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com -a someAlias
```