# Error 405 Only POST allowed when deploying code from VsCode to Org

Tags: deployment, deployment-error

I tried to deploy my code from VsCode to my Sandbox and got this error from the output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 Only POST allowed</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /services/Soap/m/50.0. Reason:
<pre>    Only POST allowed</pre></p><hr /><br/>




<!-- Body events -->
<script type="text/javascript">function bodyOnLoad(){if(window.PreferenceBits){window.PreferenceBits.prototype.csrfToken="null";};}function bodyOnBeforeUnload(){}function bodyOnFocus(){}function bodyOnUnload(){}</script>
            
</body>
</html>


<!--
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
-->
```

I'm pretty sure that I don't use REST service in my code. Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem in two different orgs, and re-authorizing the org and restarting vs code did the trick for me.

Comment: Restart VS-Code after Re-Authorizing the org solves my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. It appears that something was wrong with my project. I had other project and when I used the same connection, I was able to retrieve and deploy. You probably want to deploy from a new project.

I had tried refreshing my orgs, and delete OAuth token from the org. It did not resolve. It was working for another users in the org as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. What I did was to install the latest Salesforce CLI and plug-in versions with `sfdx update` then I restarted VS Code and everything worked just fine for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this problem, I deleted the Salesforce CLI from the connect apps, re-authorized the org, and restarted the vs code, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yes, my deployment is working fine now. I tried a bunch of solutions including yours, and it works accidentally. So I'm not sure which one solved this problem